# How to setImageResource() in Recyclerview using onClick() method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an app in which I have a menu (in an activity) created using RecyclerView. I have set onClickListener in the adapter and activity like in the code below:

Adapter class:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rVlistener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
            switch (getLayoutPosition()){
                case 0:
                    Log.d("this", "This is cow!");
                    break;
                 default:
                     Log.d("this", "This is everything else but cow!");
            }
        }
```

Activity class:

```
@Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        //something here
    }
```

I want to setImageResource whenever a relevant item is clicked from the recyclerview like below:

```
animal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey_1);
animal_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey);
animal_icon_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey_1);
animal_icon_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey_2);
animal_icon_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey_3);
animal_icon_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey_4);
```

I don't have any idea about what could be the right way to implement this. I am new to programming so it may be a very easy problem with an obvious solution. Please help me with this!

Comment: Is your `animal_image` a part of MainActivity or is it a RV item?

Comment: It is a part of mainActivity and not a part of RV item. When I try to include this in onClick() it gives an error.

Comment: Share the error log as well.

Comment: when I am adding setImageResource() in the switchCase, I have to declare these animal_image and other elements like this, 
final ImageView animal_image = findViewById(R.id.animal_image);

This is giving me an error that cannot resolve an error findViewById(int)

Comment: These elements are in another activity which I named as "core". It is the core part the app I am making.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a separate class and an Arrayadapter class which will adapt the layout acordinglly.
Do check this link to know more https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

This to know exactly what you have to do.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/